# regexp, joining two expressions together using backreferences (but is this efficient?)

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Would it be more efficient to run two regexp searches on a string:

```
public static var _isAttrib1:RegExp = /\w+ {0,}= {0,}\'[^']{0,}'/g;
public static var _isAttrib2:RegExp = /\w+ {0,}= {0,}\"[^']{0,}"/g;
```

Or combine these and run a single RegExp using back-references? They mention [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that back-references are not efficient though.

If you think there would be a benefit combining, would you mind showing me how?  I just can't get the two RegExps to combine!  This mucks up for some reason:

**EDIT3: NOTE BELOW IS WRONG!! See EDIT3 below for info.**

```
var _isAttrib1:RegExp = /\w+ {0,}= {0,}(\'|\")[^']{0,}\1/g;

var arr:Array = _isAttrib1.exec("2222 s='jjj 111'2uuuus='dd'   s=''  ")

trace(arr) // s='jjj 111','
            //but it should only give s='jjj 111' (array should have length 1 not 2).
```

Thanks!  Driven a bit potty by this.

edit: sorry, a bit of background helps:

this is in actionscript AS3 (unforunately).

I'm trying to cleanly extract the attribs from an XML that was converted to a String and had some formatting (extra spaces) applied. E.g.  to give an array of c='2',d ='4',e  =  '5'.

Edit2: Note that sometimes encasing " are used instead of encasing '.

**Edit3: The below works fine. I had confused exactly what the RegExp.exec returns. See [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#exec%28%29), specifically the g (global) section, that it is the first element in what is returned is what was matched.**

> var r:RegExp = /\w+ *= *(['"])((?!\1).|\\1)*\1/g;
>
> var str:String = "sdsdsd w='2322' r=\"fdfd dfdfd dfd\"r=''";
>
> var result:Object = r.exec(str);
>
> while (result != null) {   trace ( result[0])      result = r.exec(str); 
>   }
>   // w='2322'
>   // r="fdfd dfdfd dfd"
>   // r=''

Comment: Try `\w+ {0,}= {0,}('|").*?{0,}\1`

Comment: What if your strings have an escaped quote or apostrophe in them. Example: "I \"love\" to break parsing"

Comment: try `/\w+ *= *(['"])((?!\1).|\\\1)*\1/`  (also, what language is this?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use back reference to the captured group

```
/\w+ *= *(["']).*?\1/g;
```

Group 1 would capture `"` or `'`

`\1` would now refer the captured value in group 1 i.e either `"` or `'`

`*` is similar to `{0,}`

---

More info [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_09.html)

Comment: You can't use a backreference inside a character class.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan **You can use it**..You can remove that downvote..try [here](http://regexpal.com/) if you want to be clear with your doubts

Comment: No, You can't: http://regexr.com?351u1  Or rather, you can, but it will not work the way you think it will.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this awesome tool for you. It has a library with a description, realtime highlighting and lots lots more. Its made in flash so you know the formula is going to be compatible with what you want.

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/